# xsense ros kinetic package error-/usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: ros, sensor, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am trying to install xsens mti 3 imu driver.  When i do catkin make , i get an error

```
[ 30%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 31%] Built target robot_pose_ekf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 34%] Built target amcl_sensors
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxscontroller
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxscommon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxstypes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
xsens_ros_mti_driver-master/CMakeFiles/xsens_mti_node.dir/build.make:169: recipe for target '/home/bfd/catkin_opt/devel/lib/xsens_mti_driver/xsens_mti_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/bfd/catkin_opt/devel/lib/xsens_mti_driver/xsens_mti_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13711: recipe for target 'xsens_ros_mti_driver-master/CMakeFiles/xsens_mti_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [xsens_ros_mti_driver-master/CMakeFiles/xsens_mti_node.dir/all] Error 2
```

These folders(xscontroller-xscommon-xstypes) are in xsens package but bin/ld can not find ?ow can we solve that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358786/xsense-ros-kinetic-package-error-/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find/) by [bfdmetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45011/bfdmetu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the README in the package. it has some instructions.

Make sure the permissions are set to o+rw on your files and directories.

> sudo chmod -R o+rw xsens_ros_mti_driver *

then build xspublic from your catkin workspace:

> pushd src/xsens_ros_mti_driver/lib/xspublic && make && popd

after that run your catkin_make and it should work!

---

Originally posted by [gogrady](https://answers.ros.org/users/56952/gogrady/) with karma: 56 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bfdmetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45011/bfdmetu/) on 2020-08-07**:
It works. Thanks